# How can I trigger Rollup's "watchChange" hook in a vite plugin?

Tags: vite, rollup

I currently have a plugin that tracks the buildStart and buildEnd of my vite instance. I want to also track the recompile time when a user makes changes to a file. This is my current plugin (calling watchChange this way does not log anything to the console on a file change).

```
let endTime = null;
function Plugin() {
  let startTime = null
  return {
    name: 'my-plugin',
    buildStart() {
      startTime = new Date()
    },
    watchChange: (id) => {
      console.log("This does not log when I save/make changes to a file listed in the inputs section of my vite config");
    },
    buildEnd() {
      endTime = new Date();
   }
 }
}
```